Express Js code showing 404 error. Building a website so that it takes a correcct password and displays another page. but i click submit and get 404
I am trying to learn Express Js. I had been trying to build a website in which upon typing the correct password, another webpage called 'secrets' containing some info would be displayed. If the password is wrong, we will be redirected back to the home page. But anytime I type in the password and press submit, it shows a 404 error. Same error on Postman aswell. I am not able to find the cause of this. Kindly help.
This is my index.html code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Secrets</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Secrets</h1>
  <form action="/check" method="POST">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="text" id="password" name="password" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>

There is another html page called secret.html that will be displayed on typing correct password.
Following is my Express JS code:
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { dirname } from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

let userIsAuthorised = false;
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

function passwordCheck(req, res, next) {
  const password = req.body["password"];
  if (password === "ILoveProgramming") {
    userIsAuthorised = true;
  } else {
    userIsAuthorised = false;
  }
  next();
}

app.use(passwordCheck);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
});

app.post("/check", (req, res) => {
  if (userIsAuthorised) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/secret.html");
  } else {
    res.redirect("/");
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});


Please help! Thankyou :)


The way you are using userIsAuthorised is not safe because it is shared between all user requests. The result of the check is usually stored back on the request so it is available elsewhere and only applies to one request. 2) You said the new page/file was secrets in your intro, but you are referencing secret.html without the s. Is that it?


I suppose it's for learning purposes only but this is check is not secure at all. You can always check the code of JS loaded in your site and thus also see the password, a second problem is that anyone can just put userIsAuthorised on true and don't even need to find the password. There is a lot you can learn from the start but security like this learns you not much..
